# Restructure dataframe with premature row breaks (R or Python)

Tags: python, r, transformation, line-breaks

I received a csv file in the following format, due to an address column having contained multiple lines and forcing a premature row break for many records:

```
Name              Date           Address             Country
Jessie            01/08/2018     738 Maple Ln        US
Joe               01/15/2018     483 Watergate Pl    
Annapolis, MD     US 
Frank             01/04/2018     934 West Ave
Franklin, TN      US
```

I want to restructure the dataframe to look like this:

```
Name        Date           Address                             Country
Jessie      01/08/2018     738 Maple Ln                        US
Joe         01/15/2018     483 Watergate Pl, Annapolis, MD     US
Frank       01/04/2018     934 West Ave, Franklin, TN          US
```

The actual data contains 55 columns. Not all rows are broken in 2. Requesting a cleaner export of the data isn't plausible in this case.

I've searched for a function in R that can solve this problem which has been unsuccessful, however, I'd be comfortable giving it a shot in Python as well. There's got to be a more elegant way than reassigning each column individually.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated! : )

Comment: Is the country field always 'US'?

Comment: No, its not. Look at her example. The rows without country are not supposed to be on their own

Comment: There are multiple countries and 55 total columns in the real dataset. I believe the issue is that the original data had 2 lines in many cells within the first address column, which caused the second line of that first address and so on to break off into a new row (and in the wrong columns, of course). I don't have access to the original data, so rather than telling R to read it in properly, I have to undo what was already done to the structure of the dataframe.

Comment: Do you have a chance to distinguish the wanted row breaks from the unwanted? Please check, if they are represented by different control characters, e.g. '\n' vs '\r\n' or sth like that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following, assuming that 'adresses.txt' has the content you posted above:

```
from io import StringIO
import re
import pandas as pd

ln = ''
with open('adresses.txt') as f:
    txt = f.readline()
    header = re.split('\s+ ', txt.strip())
    ncol = len(header)
    for line in f.readlines():
        ln = ln + line.strip()
        if len(re.split('\s+ ', ln)) == ncol:
            txt += ln
            ln = '\n'
        else:
            ln += ', '

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), sep='\s+ ', engine='python')
print(df)
```

Result:

```
     Name        Date                          Address Country
0  Jessie  01/08/2018                     738 Maple Ln      US
1     Joe  01/15/2018  483 Watergate Pl, Annapolis, MD      US
2   Frank  01/04/2018       934 West Ave, Franklin, TN      US
```

The idea is to recreate the text line by line, checking every line if it has the correct number of columns. If not, concatenate the next with comma and space in between.